# NgRx - Multi level route params not able to access from CustomSerializer Router Store

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-router-store

I have a path declared like:

```
{
  path: 'app/:userId',
  children: [...AppChildrenRoutes]
}
```

And then, inside AppChildrenRoutes

```
{ path: 'feature', component: MainFeatureComponent }
```

So, at some point of my application I can have `localhost:4200/app/123/feature`.
Inside this component, with some action, I can navigate to another route like this:

```
this.router.navigate([
  'app',
  this.userId,
  'feature',
  { search: this.searchFor }
]);
```

Consider it as a big enterprise sized application that is changing architecture, to use NgRx, step by step.
So, I faced a problem with Router Store. I've set up everything and it works.
Following Router Store [docs](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/v4.1.1/docs/router-store/api.md#custom-router-state-serializer) I wrote a Custom Serializer and it looks like this

```
serialize(routerState: RouterStateSnapshot): RouterStateUrl {
  const { url } = routerState;
  const queryParams = routerState.root.queryParams;

  while (route.firstChild) {
    route = route.firstChild;
  }
  const params = route.params;

  return { url, queryParams, params };
}
```

And I found out that, considering a URI like

```
localhost:4200/app/123/feature;search=blue
```

the `route.params` returns only the `search` param, not both `userId` and `search`.

- How can I implement a `CustomSerializer` that returns all `params` from the path? (in this case, both `userId` and `search`).

I kinda tried but failed to, each iteration of the while loop, check if there was a param and add them to a object until the last one. Good, Ok or Bad approach? How could I work that and not fail?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem and solved it by extending the params object every time I go through the loop.

My CustomSerializer now looks like this:

```
export class CustomSerializer implements RouterStateSerializer<RouterStateUrl> {
serialize(routerState: RouterStateSnapshot): RouterStateUrl {
    let route = routerState.root;

    let params = {};
    while (route.firstChild) {
        params = {
            ...params,
            ...route.params
        };
        route = route.firstChild;
    }

    const {
        url,
        root: { queryParams }
    } = routerState;

    return { url, params, queryParams };
}
```

}

Comment: Took a similar, but not your approach, still accepting yours since it may work according to a specified case.

Answer (score 0):

You can select any of the parent/child route using a selector and you don't need serializer for this. You have an object of root Route and by creating a selector you can iterate through the routes and get the required parameter.

```
const selectRouter = createFeatureSelector<XStore,
    fromRouter.RouterReducerState<any>>('router');

export const selectAllRouteParam = (param: string) => createSelector(
    selectRouter,
    (router: RouterReducerState) => {
        let current = router.state.root;

        while (current) {
            if (current.params && current.params[param]) {
                return current.params[param];
            } else {
                current = current.firstChild;
            }
        }
    }
);
```

While using you can use it like this:

```
userId$ = this.store.select(selectAllRouteParam('userId'))
```

Late to the party, but I hope someone in the future will find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Actually slightly modified version (not selected as proper anwser)
works for me in Angular v16.

```
export class CustomSerializer implements RouterStateSerializer<RouterStateUrl> {
serialize(routerState: RouterStateSnapshot): RouterStateUrl {
    let route = routerState.root;

    let params = {};
    while (true) {
      params = {
        ...params,
        ...route.params,
      };

      route = route.firstChild;
      if (!route) {
        break;
      }
    }

    const {
        url,
        root: { queryParams }
    } = routerState;

    return { url, params, queryParams };
}
```